# Как записать данное выражение на языке с++?

Tags: c++, ряды, численные-методы

Y = arctg x = x – x<sup>3</sup>/3 + x<sup>5</sup>/5-...+ (-1)<sup>n</sup> x<sup>2n+1</sup>/(2n+1)+ ... (|х|<1).

Comment: с помощью функции `pow` из библиотеки `math.h` ну и понадобится еще цикл `for`

Comment: @Zhir это ряд Маклерона для арктангенса, поэтому часть `Y = arctg x ` неважна, а вот pow стоит избежать (это вычисление двузх рядов внутри - для логарифма и экспоненты)

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, и никаких `pow`!:

```
double y(double x, double eps)
{
    double s = x, t = x;
    x *= x;
    for(int i = 3;abs(t) > eps;i+=2)
        s += (t *= -x)/i;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Как бы, из криминала: при `abs(x) >= 1.` цикл не завершится. Проверка `abs(t) > eps` слишком слабая будут лишние итерации, т.к. `s` изменяется на `t/i`. Как вариант, проверять `s != sprev`, где `sprev` значение `s` на предыдущей итерации, а аргумент `eps` выкинуть, как неорганизованный.

Comment: @Serge3leo Вообще-то этот ряд сходится **только** при `|x|<=1`. И об этом прямо **сказано в условии** (вернее, там сказано еще строже — `|x|<1`). Так что что вы такое намерены проверять при `|x| > 1` — вообще непонятно...

Comment: При `x == 1.` он сходится, это раз. И, во-вторых, нормальная функция должна выдать ошибку, а зацикливание - это криминал.

Comment: @Serge3leo Да вы будете читать, что я пишу? :) Что я написал о сходимости? И нормальный вызов функции, для которой **четко указано предусловие** (а в данном случае оно указано), должен этим озаботиться сам.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще такое выращение - сумма бесконечного количества элементов, i-й элемент имеент представление:

```
     S(i) = (-1)ⁱ⁻¹ × ( xⁱ ) / i,          i = 1...∞
```

Как определить когда остановиться? Скорее всего задан какой-то критерий точности. Условия могут различаться.

Вещи которые следует учесть.

1. Значения получением возведение в степень можно запоминать из итерации в итерацию, но значения х у нас очень маленькие, поэтому накапливается ошибка. Этот эффект можно уменьшить, вычисляя степени величины `X = (1.0/x)`:

   ```
   S(i) = (-1)ⁱ⁻¹ / ( i × Xⁱ ),          i = 1...∞
   ```
2. В случае немонотонных рядов точность не определяется величиной последненго вычисленного члена.